# Create a Factor Analysis diagram/cluster visualization using R

Tags: r

I conducted a Factor Analysis in R and discovered there are 4 latent variables (factors).
I am trying to run a diagram/cluster visualization, to better represent my findings.

I would want something like this:

[image: img]

Here is my output:

```
print(factor2$loadings,cutoff = 0.3)

Loadings:
         MR2    MR1    MR4    MR3   
Inflatie                       0.796
Dobanda                        0.439
optq20    0.627                     
optq22    0.661                     
optq25    0.489                     
optq27    0.462                     
optq28                  0.651       
optq29    0.359                     
optq30                  0.636       
optq36           0.322              
optq37           0.621              
optq38           0.517              
optq39           0.620              
optq43           0.543              

                 MR2   MR1   MR4   MR3
SS loadings    1.560 1.524 1.225 0.873
Proportion Var 0.111 0.109 0.087 0.062
Cumulative Var 0.111 0.220 0.308 0.370
```

I have searched all over the Internet but could not find some useful code for that.

Thank you!

Comment: http://sachaepskamp.com/semPlot/examples might be useful

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. You should add your picture directly, since link addresses might change. Also, the SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `psych` package (which it appears you're using) has some goodies: `psych::fa.diagram()`